# Should the criteria to vote in elections for low activity exchanges be made stricter

Tags: discussion, feature-request, election

A recently savaged meta post ([Disable privileges if a user has been inactive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142739/disable-privileges-if-a-user-has-been-inactive)) seems to have been inspired by the OP's bewilderment that so many votes were cast (and not for him) in an election for DIY.stackexchange.com... He was trying to figure out why so many people participated in such a low-activity exchange, chalking it up to long-inactive users who suddenly showed up for the election. In the course of the conversation, someone pointed out that

> Users who are eligible to vote in an election receive a notification
>   in their global inbox letting them know it's voting time

Given that eligibility to vote is 150 rep points, and that you're automatically awarded 100 points when you join a new stack, it's likely that many - if not most - eligible voters on low-activity stacks may be only occasional participants (answered or asked one or two questions)... this *may* weaken the voting power of regular and active community members, and *may* tilt elections towards candidates with more recognizably from other exchanges (SO, etc) even if they haven't been particularly active in the exchange for which they are candidates.

So 3 dependent questions:

1. Do people feel that this is occurring (what do the actual voter stats tell us? Are elections in low-activity sites dominated by relatively inactive members?)
2. If it is happening, is it an issue? Maybe it's good to favor candidates with broader SE presence
3. If it is happening, and it is an issue, what's a solution? I know that any suggestion of weighting votes will send the meta crowd into a down-voting frenzy, but what about making the amount or rep required to vote in low-use exchanges higher (though this might make the voting community too small)? What about not broadcasting a specific election to eligible voters who have low-rep in that exchange AND haven't visited the site in `X months`? They can still vote if they show up, but they're not necessarily encouraged to do so.

Comment: Good job turning a horrible trainwreck into a constructive discussion.

Comment: Hm, I haven't noticed this problem; the 150 rep does require a teeny bit of activity on the site itself. If the requirement was 100 rep I'd certainly say it should be made stricter.

Comment: My immediate gut feel is that considering the low levels of participation in elections on smaller sites, the last thing we want to do is to make it harder for people to take part.

Comment: I feel there should be some minimum amount of time that you need to have been a member before you can start voting. Sure you can hop into a site and gain 200 reputation that same day, but how well do you *really* know that community if you've only been a member for one day?

Comment: It's worth discussing what the negative consequences are, even if all of the assertions are true.  Is it really a bad thing if someone who has a very positive reputation (not the number, but the support of community members) on another site has an advantage in a moderator election of a smaller SE site?  I would think that if I know X from Y, that will only help me vote more intelligently, which is *good*.

Comment: @YannisRizos don't mention the war

Comment: @animuson I got the required rep to vote in the latest SU election the day (or a day before) the election started.

Comment: On a related note, [Kevin Montrose](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose) wrote a blog post a few days ago exploring community elections: http://kevinmontrose.com/2012/08/04/trustable-online-community-elections/

Comment: @animuson - I tend to agree, though if I logged 200 rep in a day 2 years ago and haven't been back, I'm even less qualified to make good choices... some other activity indicator may be necessary if you're going to go that direction.

Comment: @BenD The thing is, though, that even if I have 10,000 (or any other number) rep on a site, that's not a guarantee of my (continued) participation or familiarity with the candidates. Maybe I only vote for candidates whose name starts with E. You can't proof against that. And on the flipside, someone having low rep or low activity doesn't mean they didn't look at each candidate's activity, comments, etc. to make an informed choice. I'll have to try to dig up some user stats.

Comment: This feels slightly like early revisions of [the first question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142660/can-self-promotion-for-a-moderator-election-go-too-far) posted by the OP of the "recently savaged meta post." That question also got downvoted, but not quite _as_ heavily.

Comment: @AnnaLear I agree to a degree (hence the second question), but I doubt that there isn't a correlation between rep and interest/involvement/stake in the exchange in question... some voters will no doubt be exceptions, but the rules that govern the election process will likely make a difference to the outcome (otherwise why not have anyone, regardless of rep or activity vote?). Regardless, I agree that rep might not be the most important indicator... and that it might not be bad to have low rep users dominating elections.

Comment: Question for the commentariat: do *you* vote in the elections on sites you only occasionally visit. I don't recall voting in the election on a site where I didn't check in regularly. Nor for that matter on a site where I didn't have circa 500 rep even though I was eligible.

Comment: As a side note to that, notice that rare posting does not imply rare viewing. There are site where I am essentially a lurker.

Comment: Association bonuses in general have outlived most of their usefulness. It worked well when there were only a handful of closed-related sites, but now you have tons of people with voting privileges on sites they know nothing about. I haven't looked at this too critically, but my impression is that this causes a strong vote skew towards questions that appeal to non-experts on smaller sites, because of the influence of 101-rep guests. I've reduced my own voting, feeling guilty. Anyway, elections are a much bigger deal and the association bonus definitely shouldn't count towards voter eligibility.

Comment: @dmckee Yes I did, on the recent SU elections... I read through the site's front page regularly though, and I had a ton of info on the candidates I voted for (and a couple I didn't). Nevertheless, I spend at least 5m reading through each candidates Meta posts before voting, having gone through the process myself I perhaps see it as a bit more serious than it actually is.

Comment: @dmckee -  I totally agree. I honestly feel like non-rep criteria would be better indicators. Much of what is tracked by badges would be better (enthusiast, civic duty, deputy, etc). These badges are too difficult to achieve to be a voter criteria, but the things that they represent (constancy, voting, cleanup) make good SE citizens, where as rep can be based on a relatively shallow relationship with the community.

Comment: @everyone - what about the suggested solution in the last question? Don't change the rules, just don't actively encourage inactive users of an exchange through the notification system? If they haven't been seen in six months (say) AND they have never been significant users, let them vote if they show up, but don't ask them to.

Comment: @ppumkin It is *extremely* difficult to get meaningful statistics out of such a small sample. When there are only a few dozen people voting, you should expect things to look very weird, whereas when you have *thousands* voting, distributions will seem more natural. Imagine trying to determine the racial makeup of a nation by using a sample of only 50 people. You would get wildly inaccurate numbers, especially for those who makeup a small percentage of the populace.

Comment: Yes I appreciate the smaller the sample the more difficult it is to analyse it. And it is even more difficult to establish a model to analyse it with. My other comment had no specific meaning, it just established popularity by trend analysis that about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could get behind the suggestion that Ben makes in the comments:

> Don't change the rules, just don't actively encourage inactive users of an exchange through the notification system? If they haven't been seen in six months (say) AND they have never been significant users, let them vote if they show up, but don't ask them to.

It is clear that the system tracks the presence of users (profiles say "last seen"), so use that as part of a condition on the delivery of the notification.

To vote, users would need

```
(rep>X) && other_conditions
```

To be notified, users would need

```
((rep>Y) || ((rep>Z) && (last_seen < W))) && other_conditions
```